# If $f$ is measured then for every real number a set {$x: f (x) = a$} measured, is the opposite true?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

If $f$ is measured then for every real number a set $\{x: f (x) = a\}$ measured, is the opposite true?
favorably we can do the following:
for all $a \in R$, $f$ measured $\Longrightarrow \{x:f(x)=a\}=\{x:f(x)\leq a\} \cap\{x:a \leq f(x)\}$ is measured. But if $\{x:f(x)=a\}$ is measured then $f$ measured, is true ???

Answer (score 1):

No.

Take $V$ to be a non Lebesgue measurable set and $f:V \to \Bbb{R}$ an injective function.

For instance $f(x)=x$

Comment: Can you give a specific example of V?

Comment: @Yaya take  $V$ to be the Vitali set.